# JavaScript validation with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have this semantic UI validation for my this form

```
<form class="ui form" method="post" action="" id="contact-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="field">
        <label> NAME</label>
        <input name="fullname" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>E -MAIL</label>
        <input name="email" type="email">

    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input name="number" type="text" id='important_number'>

    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Anything You Would Like to Ask</label>
        <textarea name="message" rows="4" cols="4"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="field">

        <input type='submit' class="ui huge olive basic button" value='Send'>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.ui.form')
            .form({
                inline: true,
                fields: {
                    fullname: {
                        identifier: 'fullname',
                        rules: [{
                                type: 'empty',
                                prompt: 'Please enter the name'
                            },

                            {
                                type: 'regExp[/^[a-zA-Z/s]*$/]',
                                prompt: 'Name should contain alphabets only!!'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    email: {
                        identifier: 'email',
                        rules: [{
                            type: 'empty',
                            prompt: 'Please enter your email'
                        }, {
                            type: 'email',
                            prompt: 'Please enter a valid email as something@example.com'
                        }]
                    },
                    number: {
                        identifier: 'number',
                        rules: [{
                            type: 'empty',
                            prompt: 'Please enter your phone number'
                        }, {
                            type: 'regExp[^[0-9]+$]',
                            prompt: 'Please enter a valid number'
                        }]
                    },
                    message: {
                        identifier: 'message',
                        rules: [{
                                type: 'empty',
                                prompt: 'Some message is required too'
                            }]
                    }}
            });
    });

</script>
```

**Also I am using ajax for form submission**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#contact-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'submit.php',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
                document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
            }



        });
    });

</script>
```

The problem is ,my form is submitting without validation ,just like > ajax does any idea how to stop form submission if the validation fails > ?? > > Edit-My php code

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';
    include 'database.php'; 

    $name=$_POST['fullname'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $phone=$_POST['number'];
      $message=trim(htmlspecialchars($db -> real_escape_string($_POST['message'])));

    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `enquiry`( `email`, `phone`, `name`, `message`) VALUES(?, ?, ?,?) ");

    $query->bind_param("ssss", $email, $phone,  $name, $message);

    $done=$query->execute();
    if ($done) {

    echo "Thanks for connecting ,We will get in touch soon";
      # code...

    }
    else {
      echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($db));
    }  
?>
```

Comment: Your PHP code does not seem to be included. You can use the ajax functions for checking for error and success to determine whether the request was either. Handle the logic and validation in your PHP file and return errors if there are any. Then decide in your `$.ajax` how to display these errors on the page.

Comment: Its working fine ,no error from backend!! its just my form is submitting without javascript validatioin

Comment: I tried async false too ,but it doesnt seems to work

Comment: I can't find any documentation on the `.form()` call you're making in your first block of code, is this a library other than jQuery that you're using for this?

Comment: its semantic ui

Comment: change `$('.ui.form').form({` to `$('#contact-form').form({` and try again

Comment: Did'nt work ,I guess I am missing something here ,the way ajax works !